# C#.net Web Request could not get 404 custom error message while calling web API but postman does

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, servicestack, webrequest

I am calling external Web API in my own Web API using ServiceStack. 
For the unsubscribed user,  external web API throws expected "404 Not found" exception with the custom message as **"No subscriber with uuid: {...uuid sent}"**. I can see it in Postman
[image]

but when I call it in my ServiceStack handler, I do not get the custom exception in exception details in the catch statement.
Following is part of my code

```
    try{

           //Create Request
            var statusUri =new Uri(urlOfExternalWebAPI, UriKind.Absolute);
            var serviceRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(statusUri);
            serviceRequest.Method = "GET";
            serviceRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization",OauthToken.TokenType + " " + OauthToken.AccessToken);
            serviceRequest.Accept = "application/json";

            //Get the response.
            using (var response = serviceRequest.GetResponse())
            {                    
                using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (responseStream != null)
                    {
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {
                            var responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }                                
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebServiceException e) // 
        {
            //Exception is not getting caught here 
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // exception is caught here but could not get the custom error message
            throw;
        }
```

Exception details:

```
System.Net.WebException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at ...Host.Request.testRequestHandler.Get(GetStatus request) 
   in ...\\testRequestHandler.cs:line 231
   at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceRunner`1.Execute(IRequest request, Object instance, TRequest requestDto)
```

**But I am not getting the custom message that I am getting in Postman in any field of the exception.**

I need the exact custom message to differentiate between 404 due to invalid URL and 404 due to invalid subscriber. Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You are trying to catch a `WebServiceException`, but the exception thrown is a `WebException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're not using [ServiceStack's Generic C# Clients](https://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client) your HTTP Request wont throw a `WebServiceException`.

You're instead using .NET's `HttpWebRequest` directly so it's only going to throw a `WebException`, but ServiceStack does also include [HTTP Utils](https://docs.servicestack.net/http-utils#exception-handling) which provides helpers for accessing Exceptions thrown by .NET's `HttpWebRequest`, e.g:

```
try 
{
    //...
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    var clientEx = ex.IsAny400();
    var notFound = ex.IsNotFound();

    HttpStatusCode? errorStatus = ex.GetStatus(); // HTTP Status Code
    string errorBody = ex.GetResponseBody();      // Error Response Body (if any)
    var errorResponse = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
    var description = errorResponse.StatusDescription;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to catch
WebException
as opposed to
WebServiceException

I don't think you should return a 404 for an invalid subscriber either unless its a clear requirement!

Comment: If you disagree on the 404, it may be useful to the OP if you briefly detail an alternative?

Comment: The OP didn't specifically ask this question. However here's a handy link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: Cool, so do you suggest `418`? Or do you think there's a more appropriate one the OP could use?

Comment: Actually third party API returns the 404 in case of invalid subscriber something we can't control...